# In which scenarios do you use encapsulation?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I would like to know in what scenarios you use encapsulation. The purpose of this question **is collaborative**. So feel free to share your own experience when the subject is encapsulation.

Some scenarios:

**Calculated property**

```
public class Order {

    private List<ListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    public double getTotal() {
        double total = 0;
        for(ListItem listItem: listItems)
            total += listItem.getQuantity() * listItem.getPropduct().getPrice();

        return total;
    }

}
```

**Self-validating domain objects**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
            throw new NotEmptyException("name", name);
        }

        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Makes use of other kind of classes for some special behavior**

```
public class Person {

    private MutableInt id = new MutableInt();

    /**
      * Integer itself is immutable
      */
    public Integer getId() {
        retur id.intValue();
    }

}
```

**Conversion**

```
public class Person {

     public String enabled;

     public boolean isEnabled() {
         return "Y".equals(enabled);
     }

}
```

Comment: Your `isEnabled` method could be shortened to `return "Y".equals(enabled);`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply, I prefer to use strong encapsulation in **all** non-private APIs that I design/implement.

The only case where habitually don't use strong encapsulation is with **private** nested classes that are (and need to be) little more than ersatz `struct` declarations.  My reasoning is that the private class is sufficiently encapsulated by being nested and private.

I am also prepared to relax encapsulation (a bit) if there are compelling performance reasons for doing this.  This relaxation usually consists of leaking internal arrays / collections when the cost of copying them is prohibitive.  And it always makes me feel uncomfortable doing this ...

Comment: +1 Nivas.

re: struct. I find that every time I use a struct instead of a class, I end up having to tear the struct out later and replace it with a class anyway.

re: performance. performance issues in my code involve database access 99% of the time.  I've never had a performance issue caused by plain Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I encapsulate when there is a scenario in which the user can screw it up. e.g., if I was writing a class that displayed text, I would not encapsulate the fact that I hold a string, because any string is valid for display.

Encapsulation exists for validation and interface change. If you have a parameter that needs no validation (and the interface is well-defined), there's no point in encapsulating it, especially if you use a language which doesn't come with any in-built tools for it, like Java (tools being, for example, C# properties).

Encapsulation is a tool like any other and should not be thrown all over everywhere just because you can.